# messed up my boot/efi, couldn't boot into anything, now boot repair is not working either

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, boot-repair

i "accidentally" messed up the boot/efi folder when i was trying to replace it with one i had copied earlier(stupid I know)

When i rebooted the computer i could not boot into ubuntu 14.04 nor windows 7, asking me to insert boot media.

So now i'm trying to use boot repair, but it gives me this: "The boot of your pc is in legacy mode. Please change it to EFI mode."

I am not entirely sure what this means in my case since my computer should be running in UEFI mode, but frankly i'm pretty confused right now.

All of this was done by me in a sleep deprived stressful state, so please don't blame me to much, i would be very thankful if anyone could give me some pointers! :)

Comment: You have to go into the bios to enable uefi. Hit delete or f12 or something to get into the bios.

Comment: @mttdbrd - you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Whether default boot of hard drive is UEFI or BIOS, you choose to boot from a USB flash drive with either UEFI or CSM/BIOS. Normally flash drive clearly says UEFI & name of flash drive. But for CSM/BIOS/Legacy mode it will just show name of flash drive. So be sure to boot flash drive in UEFI mode.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that @oldfred? i have a list of bootable devices and uefi dosn't show up next to the usb harddrive.. in my boot settings, it is already set to UEFI/LEGACY

Comment: You do need to have UEFI on. On my new ASUS motherboard it would only boot flash drive in UEFI mode with a UEFI setting of UEFI only, not even UEFI & CSM, UEFI first. But most have posted examples with both choices since Ubuntu installer is both. You do have 64 bit version as it is the only one that is UEFI boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

UEFI was enabled on my motherboard, I was using http://www.pendrivelinux.com/, which apparently didn’t boot me as UEFI.

Using Rufus worked, then i had to use recommended boot repair, and afterwards use windows boot repair to get windows working as well!

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into the bios to enable uefi. Hit delete or f12 or something to get into the bios. From there you'll need to find the setting to enable UEFI.